# Does encoding a secret affect security?

Tags: randomness, encoding

My question is simple. I have a secret that is generated with a 10 byte long pseudorandom generator library (e.g. Java's [SecureRandom](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html)), that in theory provides a security equivalent to $2^{40}$ (birthday bound). This secret is encoded afterwards (e.g. Base64). This is supposed to reduce entropy, while extending the string lenght.

If I want to brute force the secret, does the encoding have any negative impact on the protection? (in other words, does it facilitate the brute forcing at all?)
My intuition is that the security is not affected, but I learnt to be extra cautious with this sort of things.

Comment: How do you figure the entropy reduction?  Are you talking the reduced entropy rate of 8 bits/byte to 6 bits/character?

Comment: By the way, 'denigrate' means to _say_ something is bad, but does _not_ mean that description is correct. In fact something that is denigrated is usually in fact _good_. If you mean 'reduce', say 'reduce'.

Comment: Yes, I mean the entropy reduction in terms of entropy per byte: where there could be 256 possibilities before now this set is reduced. But of course, this increases the string length

Comment: You are right, @dave_thompson_085, perhaps I have not chosen the most accurate verb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A byte is 8 bits; 10 random bytes are therefore 80 random bits, which is $2^{80}$ equiprobable alternatives (not $2^{40}$), which is 80 bits of entropy.  (Unless your 10 byte random string is actually an ASCII representation of a 40-bit hexadecimal value; since `SecureRandom` outputs full range `byte[]` I'll assume it's not that.)

> This secret is encoded afterwards (e.g. Base64). This is supposed to reduce entropy, while extending the string length.

This "entropy reduction" isn't real.  Any Base64 encoder is a one-to-one function—each of the $2^{80}$ inputs in your example is mapped to a unique output.  There are therefore $2^{80}$ unique possible outcomes as well, each one equally likely, and thus 80 bits of entropy like originally.

What's probably confusing you is that the binary representation of the Base64-encoded string is longer than 80 bits, but it's not made of uniform random bits, so in that sense it's not a full-entropy string—the 14-ish bytes in the Base64 string are 112 bits long but would only collectively have 80 bits of entropy.

> If I want to brute force the secret, does the encoding has any negative impact on the protection?

Not really.  Again, $2^{80}$ possible outcomes, all of them equally likely.

Comment: You are forgetting the birthday bound to calculate $2^{80}$, don't you?

Comment: Your answer is what my intuition says, and what seems correct (except from the fact that you are assuming more security - $2^{80}$ than what I think it has - $2^{40}$). Note that I have not accepted yet because I am looking for a potential smart answer that can state the opposite (in cryptography, many security breaks are counterintuitive)

Comment: @user1156544 80 bits of entropy provide 40 bits of security against collisions when applying the birthday paradox directly. They are still 80 bits of entropy. Collision attacks may, or may not, be relevant depending on the context of the protocol or algorithm being studied.

Comment: Agree. That is why I never said it has an entropy of $2^{40}$ but a **provided security** equivalent to $2^{40}$.

Comment: @user1156544 It only provides 40 bits of security in few contexts. This result cannot be generalized like you do. Even the reduction to half the bits is just a rule of thumb and cannot be applied when one seeks a probability of collisions of 2^-32.

Comment: Well, I better consider worst case scenario, and I know it is a probability (not a fact) and an approximation (not an exact calculation).

Comment: @user1156544: Your question is about the *entropy* of a *secret random value* that an adversary tries to "brute force" (i.e., guess), not about the probability of collisions or some other such scenario where the birthday bound applies. So the security model is something like this: (1) honest party secretly picks a value uniformly at random from a set of size $2^{80}$; (2) adversary must guess that value. The latter takes $2^{79}$ guesses on average, which is 80-bit security.

Comment: I think we are straying from the original question but it's interesting. You two are totally right, BF a SINGLE secret would have had a 50% prob at $2^{40}$ tries (although I am not sure how you get the $2^{79}$ avg). If the secret is part of a larger system, there is a 50% prob to generate a duplicated secret after ~$2^{40}$ generations. Apologies for the misunderstanding. Do we agree on this?

Comment: Oh, I think I see now where the $2^{79}$ comes from, so the 50% chance after $2^{40}$ is incorrect - there are less values in this calculation